# Regex issue with building a file system crawler

Tags: ruby, regex, macos, filesystems, web-crawler

I am building a crawler to search my file system for specific documents containing specific information. However, the regex part is leaving me a little perplexed. I have a testfile on my desktop containing 'teststring' and a test credit card number '4060324066583245' and the code below will run properly and find the file containing `teststring`:

```
require 'find'
count = 0

Find.find('/') do |f|              # '/' for root directory on OS X
  if f.match(/\.doc\Z/)            # check if filename ends in desired format
    contents =  File.read(f)
      if /teststring/.match(contents) 
      puts f
      count += 1
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} sensitive files were found"
```

Running this confirms that the crawler is working and properly finding matches. However, when I try to run it for finding the test credit card number it fails to find a match:

```
require 'find'
count = 0

Find.find('/') do |f|              # '/' for root directory on OS X
  if f.match(/\.doc\Z/)            # check if filename ends in desired format
    contents =  File.read(f)
      if /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/.match(contents) 
      puts f
      count += 1
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} sensitive files were found"
```

I checked the regex on rubular.com with `4060324066583245` as a piece of test data, which is contained in my test document, and Rubular verifies that the number is a match for the regex. To sum things up:

1. The crawler works on the first case using `teststring` - verifying that the crawler is properly scanning my file system and reading contents of the desired file type
2. Rubular verifies that my regex successfully matches my test credit card number `4060324066583245`
3. The crawler fails to find the test credit card number.

Any suggestions? I'm at a loss why Rubular shows the regex as working but the script won't work when run on my machine.

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac OS and Linux include `grep` which can make short work of this, and will run faster than Ruby.

Comment: I'm on OS X but I would like the program to run on Windows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` and `$` are anchors that tie the match to the start and end of the string, respectively.

Therefore, `^[0-9]{4}$` will match `"1234"`, but not `"12345"` or `" 1234 "` etc.

You should be using word boundaries instead:

```
if contents =~ /\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?\b/
```

Comment: Side question - is there a significant difference between using `=~` and `match()` in this case? The ruby documentation shows that they both can be used for matching, but `=~` can be used for showing the location of the matched data.

Comment: @Anconia: Both match equally; I prefer the shorter version, but I guess that's a matter of choice if all you're doing is checking whether there is a match, not what exactly was matched or where.

Comment: Technically, `^` and `$` anchor to the beginning and end of the *line*, `\A` and `\z` anchor to the beginning and end of the *string*.

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah yes, that's that Ruby oddity where `/s` is `/m` and where `/m` doesn't exist...thanks!